# Angular9-MatDatePicker: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have looked at SEVERAL other posts about this and I'm still having a problem implementing ngmodel binding with matdatepicker.

My HTML:

```html
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Start Date</mat-label>
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="searchStartDate" [min]="minDate" [max]="maxDate" [matDatepicker]="picker">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"> 
    </mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

I get this error for the html code above: `Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.`

TS file associated with html code above:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule }   from '@angular/forms'; 
// I threw this in just in case^^


@Component({
  selector: 'app-dash-home',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./example.component.scss']
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {
  searchStartDate: Date; searchEndDate: Date
  constructor() {
    const todaysDate = new Date();
    this.minDate = new Date(todaysDate.getFullYear() - 5, 0, 1);
    this.maxDate = new Date(todaysDate.getFullYear(), todaysDate.getMonth(), todaysDate.getDate());
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

I have been trying to debug this issue for several hours now and I'm not sure if this is an Angular v9 issue. 
I found a stackblitz example from another stackoverflow question which illustrates the expected behavior here (running Angular v7 I think): https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y8hqyn-52t76k?file=app%2Fdatepicker-value-example.html

Notice how the stackblitz example initializes to today's date? That's the behavior I'm trying to emulate. I also included my app.module.ts below just in case.

File: app.module.ts

```js
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
imports: [...
    FormsModule,
...]
```

Thanks for all the anticipated help and support

EDIT:

Adding the module files for which ExampleComponent belongs to:

examplecomponent.module.ts:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MaterialModule } from '../../assets/material';



import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [
    ...,
    FormsModule
  ]
})
export class ExampleComponentModule{ }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that the `FormsModule` is imported in the module that your `ExampleComponent` is declared

Comment: It is imported in both app.module.ts and the ts file please see the code blocks

Comment: I saw that, is ExampleComponent declared in the app.module.ts or is it declared in another module?  If it is declared in another module, try importing it there too.

Comment: Actually... no it is not. Example component belongs to a module within the main website. So there's app which is the main website -> Module 1 (dashboard) -> which has ExampleComponent as a declaration.

Comment: Ok, then import FormsModule in the Module 1 (dashboard) and see if that doesn't fix it

Comment: That was it... I never Imagined that could be the problem. Thank you!!!